# Spring Repository method complains about field not found

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Spring Data Neo4j in my project and I'm having issues with naming conventions for repositories.

This is a simple class containing only one field and the getters/setters

```
@RelationshipEntity
public class ScoredRelationship
{
  protected Float score;
}
```

and the class below extends it with other kind of fields

```
@RelationshipEntity(
    type = RecommenderRelTypes.GOV_CONSUMER_TO_GOV_CONSUMER_SIMILARITY)
public class GovConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity extends ScoredRelationship
{ // Other fields}
```

To access the relationship, I'm using the usual repository class

```
public interface GovConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarityRepository extends
    GraphRepository<GovConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity>
{

  public Set<GovConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity> findByScoreGreaterThan(Float value);

  public Set<GovConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity>
     findByScoreGreaterThanOrderByScoreDesc(Float value);

  public Set<GovConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity>
     findTopXByScoreGreaterThanOrderByScoreDesc(int limit, Float score);
}
```

This code compiles well. However, whenever I'm trying to use one of the methods, `Spring` return a series of exception or doesn't act as intended.

F.e. `#findByScoreGreaterThan(0.3f)` always returns an empty set. However, invoking a `findAll()` and printing all the scores it actually has a lot of objects with a score greater than 0.3.

In the second and third case, it always throws an exception saying

```
Caused by: Unknown identifier `score`.
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.symbols.SymbolTable.evaluateType(SymbolTable.scala:60)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.expressions.Identifier.evaluateType(Identifier.scala:51)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.expressions.Expression.assertTypes(Expression.scala:53)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.SortPipe$$anonfun$assertTypes$1.apply(SortPipe.scala:34)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.SortPipe$$anonfun$assertTypes$1.apply(SortPipe.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.SortPipe.assertTypes(SortPipe.scala:33)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.<init>(PipeWithSource.scala:27)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.SortPipe.<init>(SortPipe.scala:29)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.SortBuilder.apply(SortBuilder.scala:33)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl.prepareExecutionPlan(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:49)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl.<init>(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:33)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine$$anonfun$prepare$1.apply(ExecutionEngine.scala:67)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine$$anonfun$prepare$1.apply(ExecutionEngine.scala:67)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.LRUCache.getOrElseUpdate(LRUCache.scala:37)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.prepare(ExecutionEngine.scala:67)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:59)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:63)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngine.parseAndExecuteQuery(CypherQueryEngine.java:61)
```

How could be possible? I mean, the class obviously has the `score` field. Also, executing the simple `#findByScoreGreaterThan(float value)` doesn't throw any exception, but at the same the latter method always returns an empty set.

EDIT:
These are the queries used by Spring. Actually, they seems right

```
Executing cypher query: START `govConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity`=node:__types__(className="it.cerict.recommender.persistence.neo4j.GovConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity") WHERE `govConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity`.`score`! > {0} RETURN `govConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity` params {0=0.3}

Executing cypher query: START `govConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity`=node:__types__(className="it.cerict.recommender.persistence.neo4j.GovConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity") WHERE `govConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity`.`score`! > {0} RETURN `govConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity` ORDER BY score DESC params {0=0.3}
```

EDIT2: I've also tried to change the `score` type from `Float` to `float` with no further improvements.

Comment: Try - ByOrderBy -  public Set<GovConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity>
     findByScoreGreaterThanByOrderByScoreDesc(Float value);

Comment: @farrellmr This returns in a compile time error saying `Invalid derived query! No property greaterThanBy found for type Float! Traversed path: GovConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity.score.`

Comment: @farrellmr take also a look at my edit, because the first method also doesn't act as expected.

Comment: Im not convinced you can do orderBy on neo queries. I think it has to be a custom query

Comment: @farrellmr well, it actually does support it. Take also a look at the queries I posted in the edit.

Comment: sorry i meant order by

Comment: @farrellmr the problem is that it always returns empty set even without order by.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug related to `Spring Data Neo4j`. Looking to the query executed, it is clear that it searches for nodes, while it should search for relationships.

I changed the `#findByScoreGreaterThanOrderByScoreDesc()` method using the `@Query` annotation that specifies the following `Cypher` query

```
START `govConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity`=rel:__rel_types__(className="it.cerict.recommender.persistence.neo4j.GovConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity") WHERE `govConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity`.`score`! > 0.3 RETURN `govConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity` ORDER BY `govConsumerToGovConsumerSimilarity`.`score` DESC;
```